# log4j: abbreviate/shorten package names

Tags: java, log4j, logging

How would i abbreviate/shorten package names in log generated using log4j. i.e. instead of `com.longpackage.anotherpackage.lastpackage.MyClass` i want `c.l.a.l.MyClass`. I have seen this in [Artifactory](http://www.jfrog.com/products.php) logs, but can't figure how to achieve this using log4j.

Comment: But if you're not reading through long package names, are you really doing Java?  Are you really getting the whole Java Experience®?  Seriously though, good question.

Comment: @andronikus When reading logs, you usually need just the class name. If multiple classes happen to have the same name, the abbreviated package names suffice to disambiguate in practice.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

It turns out that this is possible using log4j after all(tested using [v1.2.16](http://www.apache.org/dyn/closer.cgi/logging/log4j/1.2.16/apache-log4j-1.2.16.zip)), thanks to [Tomasz Nurkiewicz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891910/log4j-abbreviate-shorten-package-names/7891945#7891945) for pointing me to [LogBack](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord). The feature, ConversionWord, is available using the [EnhancedPatternLayout](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/EnhancedPatternLayout.html) layout.

From the javadoc

`... For example, for the category name "alpha.beta.gamma" the pattern %c{2} will output the last two elements ("beta.gamma"), %c{-2} will remove two elements leaving "gamma", %c{1.} will output "a.b.gamma" ...`

I'm using JBoss and had to upgrade log4j and use the above layout.

Comment: Example:


`log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.EnhancedPatternLayout
    log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%-5p %c{1.} [%t]: %m%n`

Comment: The Java code behind logback's "ConversionWord" / LoggerConverter is the TargetLengthBasedClassNameAbbreviator class: https://github.com/qos-ch/logback/blob/master/logback-classic/src/main/java/ch/qos/logback/classic/pattern/TargetLengthBasedClassNameAbbreviator.java.

Comment: log4j:ERROR Category option "1." not a decimal integer.

Answer (score 60):

Artifactory uses [Logback](http://logback.qos.ch/):

> Projects known to rely on logback:
>
> - [...]
> - Artifactory

which has this nice feature called [Conversion Word](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/layouts.html#conversionWord):

| Conversion specifier | Logger name | Result |
| --- | --- | --- |
| %logger | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar |
| %logger{0} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | Bar |
| %logger{5} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | m.s.s.Bar |
| %logger{10} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | m.s.s.Bar |
| %logger{15} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | m.s.sample.Bar |
| %logger{16} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | m.sub.sample.Bar |
| %logger{26} | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar | mainPackage.sub.sample.Bar |

Comment: Nice! "Conversion word" is what I was after.

Comment: There you go. The table looks neater now. Hopefully SO will support markdown's table format one day and this will look better.