# log4j2: Abbreviate / shorten package names

Tags: java, log4j2

This question is the same question as this question (But for **log4j2**):
[log4j: abbreviate/shorten package names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891910/log4j-abbreviate-shorten-package-names)

Comment: @DwB I don't believe slf4j specifies patterns as part of its API. Those fall to the implementations.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This is quite simple and is documented at http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/layouts.html#PatternLayout. In your `patternLayout` just specify `%c{1.}` in the pattern to get the abbreviated `Logger` name. If you want the class name instead, use `%C{1.}`.

Comment: How do I collapse the first 4 elements into 1 letter? e.g. 
`com.acme.commons.framework.backend.Foo` into `c.a.c.f.backend.Foo` ?

Comment: Seehttps://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2785 and https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/LOG4J2-2401