# abbreviate or shorten the logger name to initials with python logging

Tags: python, python-3.x, logging

I'm trying to achieve a behavior available in log4j, which is described in [this SO Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7891910/log4j-abbreviate-shorten-package-names)

Instead of the logger producing the following output (notice the full module name)

```
DEBUG    aproject.bpackage.cclass:filename.py:79 log message 1
```

I'd like to only have the initials of the logger `name`:

```
DEBUG    a.b.c:filename.py:79 log message 1
```

Trying to figure out the correct format string with [the manual](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/logging.html#logrecord-attributes), but no mention of initials for the logger `name`

Note that loggers are initialized with the module name as convention:
`logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)`

Comment: In response to your comment on my answer: you can do this with any handler, I just used `StreamHandler` in the answer for illustration purposes. The key thing is the custom formatter.

Comment: Thanks @VinaySajip, my comment was if it can be done **without** a handler.

Comment: No, because a handler is what provides output, formatted by its formatter. Your comment mentioned without a `StreamHandler` specifically, so it wasn't clear you meant _any_ handler.

Comment: @VinaySajip - you're right, I was imprecise with my question. Thank you for the clarification.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no out-of-the-box functionality for this, but you can achieve the desired result using something like this:

```
import logging

class CustomFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        saved_name = record.name  # save and restore for other formatters if desired
        parts = saved_name.split('.')
        # import pdb; pdb.set_trace()
        record.name = '.'.join(p[0] for p in parts)
        result = super().format(record)
        record.name = saved_name
        return result

h = logging.StreamHandler()
f = CustomFormatter('%(name)-6s %(message)s')
h.setFormatter(f)
root = logging.getLogger()
root.addHandler(h)
root.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
logging.getLogger('alpha.beta.gamma').debug('foo')
logging.getLogger('delta.epsilon.zeta').debug('bar')
logging.getLogger('eta.theta').debug('baz')
```

When run, the above script outputs

```
a.b.g  foo
d.e.z  bar
e.t    baz
```

Comment: Do you think this can be done without a `logging.StreamHandler()`?